# How to exclude a node/mesh from the scene's fog in sceneKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit

Looking through [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNScene_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012015-CLSCHSCNScene-SW29), I fail to see how to exclude a node from the fog. For instance, I have far meshes that I wish would remain unaffected by the distance fog.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no API to exclude a node from the fog (except if you provide your custom shader with a SCNProgram of course, but you then need to compute the lighting and sample your textures yourself).

Comment: If you'd like to see such API, it's probably a good idea to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).